# Hide either one of the option by selected value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two identical `select` lists like follows:

```
<select id="system" name="system[1][1]">
  Option 1
  Option 2
  Option 3
</select>

<select id="system" name="system[1][2]">
  Option 1
  Option 2
  Option 3
</select>
```

I want the user select either one of this select `option2`. If user choose `option2` in `first select` then hide the `option2` in `second select` and vice versa.

### Example:

```
var select1 = document.querySelector('[name="system[1][1]"]');
var select2 = document.querySelector('[name="system[1][2]"]');

if (select1.value == '2') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').show();
} else if (select2.value == '2') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').show();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
}
```

Which I think is bit of messy. Is it any elegant way that I can achieve this in `Javascript` or `Jquery`?

Thanks

Comment: The 2 IDs are same...

Comment: Yes. Thats why I have chosen to do it by `name`.

Comment: IDs should be unique: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Check this out vinay - https://jsfiddle.net/momswvk1/ when u are select the first option with value 2 2nd select optin will be hide.

Comment: Thanks @I'mback One request is that when you de select the option 2 to option 1, can't see the two options in select2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
<select id="system" name="system[1][1]">
    <option value="optioin-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="system" name="system[1][2]">
    <option value="optioin-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery :

```
jQuery('select').change(function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var selectboxId = $(this).attr('name');
    jQuery('select option').show();
    if(selectboxId == 'system[1][1]') {
        jQuery('select[name="system[1][2]"]').find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
    } else if(selectboxId == 'system[1][2]') {
        jQuery('select[name="system[1][1]"]').find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Pratik. When change back to first option, the second list does not show the two options. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Add jQuery('select option').show(); before if condition

updated my previous answer

Comment: Will it work if we have more options in both select box. But the requirement will be option2?

Comment: yes it will work with more options as well, but be sure to keep the values same for the options in both selectboxes If you want to pass different values in option than you can use data attribute in option.
Tell me if that is the case, i'll update my answer

Comment: Hi, I have added upto 5 options in both select box with your jquery its not working. Help please!

Comment: please add your code
would be better if you add it in jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116202/discussion-between-vinay-and-pratik-deshmukh).

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/momswvk1/1/)

I hope this is what ur looking for ?

**Html**

```
<select id="system1" name="system[1][1]">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="system2" name="system[1][2]">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function(){

var select1 = document.querySelector('[name="system[1][1]"]');
var select2 = document.querySelector('[name="system[1][2]"]');

if (select1.value == '2') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').show();
} else if (select2.value == '2') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').show();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
} else if (select1.value == '1') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').show();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
} else if (select2.value == '1') {
  $('select[name="system[1][2]"] option[value="2"]').show();
  $('select[name="system[1][1]"] option[value="2"]').hide();
}

});
});
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks and its worked as I expected. But the repetitive same thing is not a problem in this case?

Comment: Yea of course u wont find any probs in this case i hope so

Comment: I am asking is it the best we can achieve the result? Hope it's not code smells. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach (note the change of `id` properties, this is not optional, it's required in order to have valid HTML):

```js
// cache the relevant <select> elements, here we use
// a CSS attribute-selector to get those <select>
// elements whose id attribute begins with 'system':
var selectElements = $('select[id^=system]');

// binding the anonymous function as the event-handler
// for the 'change' event, using the on() method:
selectElements.on('change', function() {

  // we retrieve the index of the selected option from
  // the changed <select> element:
  var chosen = this.selectedIndex;

  // we hide all the previously-selected <select> elements:
  selectElements.hide()
    // we find the <select> element at the same index as
    // the chosen <option>:
    .eq(chosen)
    // and then show that element:
    .show();
})
```

```css
/* This is just to give a visual cue to
   show which of the elements is currently
   visible on the page: */
#system1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em fuchsia;
}
#system2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="system1" name="system[1][1]">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="system2" name="system[1][2]">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vy9o7gmy/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks David. Yes I understand that and it's an existing code and I could not change the ID attribute.

Comment: Well, yes, you can (even if only with jQuery: $('select[id^=system]').prop('id', function(current, index) { return current + index; });`) It is, though, a bit of a faff. But it's absolutely worth changing - however difficult - to enable more reliable functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the advise David. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

although there are some answers, here's what i came up with:

```
$("select").on("change", function() { //on any change event in all selects
  var currentSelection = $(this); //save the used select box 

  //then take all selects, except the activated one, take the 'option' childs and iterate through them
  $("select").not(currentSelection).find("option").each(function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == currentSelection.val()) //if option value = chosen value
        $(this).hide();   //hide it
      else                //if not
        $(this).show();   //show it (to reshow already hidden elements) 
    });
  });
```

this works with endless options! but as soon, as you have more then 2 selects, you have to rework the 'show' part of this script...

here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usksL955/1/

Comment: Hi errand, Thanks. But when you choose first option in `select 1`, then the first option in `select2` is hide. I dont want that. My requirement is just the `option value = 2`.

Comment: feel free to adapt the approach to fit your solution!